Hair points in wrong direction when edited and rendered
I have modeled a hedgehog (with placeholder limbs, don't judge!). It has spikes as coming out of its back. When I render with the hair in its default placement things look fine.

But if I make even a tiny edit using Particle Edit mode the hair seems to come out of the backface. I've checked the normals and they seem to be correct. If I delete the edit, it goes back to rendering correctly.
It's the same bug in both Cycles and EEVEE.

Edit to add settings. Animation and custom properties sections are empty.


Show more of your particle settings. This could be a few different things.

I've added a screenshot

The problem seems to be that I had a mirror modifier and that the hair was using the modifier stack. Applying the mirror modifier seems to have fixed it.
